# PaddleOCR installation failure

Tags: paddleocr

when I am trying to install PaddleOCR, I'm running into an installation error while trying to install pymupdf. I'm currently on Python 3.8.16

> error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1
> [end of output]
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.   Rolling back uninstall of PyMuPDF   Moving to
> /Users/derekbai/.pyenv/versions/3.8.16/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyMuPDF-1.21.1.dist-info/
> from
> /Users/derekbai/.pyenv/versions/3.8.16/lib/python3.8/site-packages/~yMuPDF-1.21.1.dist-info
> Moving to
> /Users/derekbai/.pyenv/versions/3.8.16/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fitz/
> from
> /Users/derekbai/.pyenv/versions/3.8.16/lib/python3.8/site-packages/~itz
> error: legacy-install-failure
>
> × Encountered error while trying to install package. ╰─> PyMuPDF

Answer (score 3):

It works for me:

pip install "paddleocr>=2.0.1" --upgrade PyMuPDF==1.21.1

Thanks to https://github.com/AlienKevin

Comment: this solution works fine!